# Laravel - unable to loop in the first relationship, but within the relationship works fine

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

My current nested for loop:

```
@foreach($auditResults->map->questionDetail as $detail)
    @include('dropdownQuestion', [
        'answer' => $auditResults,
        'detail' => $detail,
        'question' => $detail->auditQuestion
    ])
@endforeach
```

As you can see, I want to return the `$auditResults` within the loop as `answer`, but this current set up doesn't work.

If I change the for loop to this (which logically makes sense):

```
@foreach($auditResults as $result)
    @foreach($result->map->questionDetail as $detail)
        @include('dropdownQuestion', [
            'answer' => $result,
            'detail' => $detail,
            'question' => $detail->map->auditQuestion
        ])
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

I get `Trying to get property of non-object`.

How can I loop and return the `$auditResults` without getting a non-object property? Many thanks.

**DD of $auditResults collection:**

```
Collection {#400 ▼
  #items: array:18 [▼
    0 => Audit {#404 ▼
      #fillable: array:4 [▶]
      #attributes: array:7 [▶]
      #original: array:7 [▶]
      #observables: []
      #relations: array:1 [▼
        "questionDetail" => AuditQuestionDetail {#426 ▶}
      ]
      #touches: []
      +timestamps: true
      #hidden: []
      #visible: []
      #guarded: array:1 [▶]
    }
    1 => Audit {#405 ▶}
    2 => Audit {#406 ▶}
    3 => Audit {#407 ▶}
    4 => Audit {#408 ▶}
    5 => Audit {#409 ▶}
    6 => Audit {#410 ▶}
    7 => Audit {#411 ▶}
    8 => Audit {#412 ▶}
    9 => Audit {#413 ▶}
```

Comment: Could you provide the `dd()` of `$auditResults`?

Comment: @manniL - attached to the description.

Comment: I think error is on $detail->map->auditQuestion. Do you eager load map? Remove the line and see if it works.

Comment: Similar thoughts here as @train_fox. I cannot see why there is need for calling `map` in this case: `@foreach($result->questionDetail as $detail)`

Comment: If I change it to `@foreach($result->questionDetail as $detail)`, the error is shown on @train_fox's original suggestion of the `$detail->map->auditQuestion`. Do I need another nested loop to access this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume map is one to one relation. You should check if there is any relation data before using it:

```
@foreach($auditResults as $result)
  @if ($result->map->count())
    @if ($result->map->questionDetail->count())
      @foreach($result->map->questionDetail as $detail)
          @include('dropdownQuestion', [
              'answer' => $result,
              'detail' => $detail,
              'question' => $detail->map->auditQuestion
          ])
      @endforeach
     @endif
  @endif
@endforeach
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, unfortunately the above returns `Call to a member function count() on null`.

Comment: Which one? map or questionDetail?

Comment: It doesn't actually say where it's failing. It says line 108 which is above the for loop on a blank line.

Comment: Certainly you missed some relationships. Check your relationships. Try in tinker to fetch relations separately to check relationships.